# PHP ( Reading URL arguments )

Tags: php, url, arguments, xampp

How to use username url in php !!
I want to do like this
when requesting page
http://localhost/profile/superrcoder
it has to show profile page of superrcoder
example, in facebook, https://www.facebook.com/facebook shows facebook fan page

I dont hava any idea to implement it!

I'm using XAMPP in windows.

Comment: You need URL routing, so when your calling http://localhost/profile/superrcoder it calls http://localhost/profile.php?user=supercoder or you should use a framework which supports it (MVC).... Easy way would be to add an htacces and mask the url to a standard basic PHP file with a querystring :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to use a rewrite rule for Apache and parse it with PHP.

You have to enable mod_rewrite for your XAMPP installation.

Create .htaccess in the root of your localhost with the following content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?uq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, in the index.php as the last rewrite rule refers to, you should be able to do something like:

```
<?php
  $url_parts = explode('/', $_GET['uq']);
  var_dump($url_parts);
?>
```

The array dumped by PHP sould give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

It uses url rewriting to make the url look like that but normally it's passing information via $_GET. So the url has parameters and values such as username=example but is rewritten to look 'pretty'.

Have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I believe you should be using `.htaccess` to cause the redirections, in conjunction with PHP's database abilities. For example:

## profile.php

```
if (!empty($_GET['user'])) { 
    //Do some crazy database stuff to get the profile info or page.
}
```

## .htaccess

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1

(Note the codes are incomplete, they are just examples)